# What is the citation ID for using EndNote (.enl) libraries to cite in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

This question has been asked several times in several different ways...

**See:**

[R markdown citation identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825541/r-markdown-citation-identifiers)

[How to cite references in R Markdown from Endnote library (.enl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45181449/how-to-cite-references-in-r-markdown-from-endnote-library-enl)

...but has yet to be answered satisfactorily.

So my question is: **how do you locate the citation ID for EndNote libraries to use in R Markdown?** As others have pointed out, all the examples are for .bib libraries, which work seamlessly (especially so with the `citr` package add-in).

Another Stack user found that you cannot use citation IDs that are entirely numeric, and worries that since EndNote indexes its documents using numbers, this may be prohibitive for using EndNote for R Markdown citations. See below.

[R Markdown Not Rendering Citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644665/r-markdown-not-rendering-citation)

I am aware I could export my EndNote library as a .bib file and then simply use BibTeX citing methods (which I may do, since `citr` makes for a easy-to-use GUI-like experience). But I would still like to find out how to make EndNote libraries work properly.

Thanks for your help.